# Cannot create composer .cache directory in Laravel

Tags: laravel, terminal, composer-php

> Cannot create cache directory
> /home/hasib/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory
> is not writable. Proceeding without cache
>
> Cannot create cache directory /home/hasib/.composer/cache/files/, or
> directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache

This message is giving me when I run the command `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using? Why is the `cache` directory not present in `bootstrap` directory as in the default structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to set right permissions for `cache` directory and all files and directories inside it. Run this command:

```
chmod -R 775 /home/hasib/.composer/cache
```